# Android studio Sdk Manager not opening

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

so when i try to open my sdk manager (or my adv manager) in android studio i get this error message:

Cannot launch SDK manager.
Output:

Error: Unable to access jarfile lib\archquery.jar
Invalid path
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
ERROR: SWT folder '' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.

("den angivede fil blev ikke fundet" means: the stated file was not found)

i think the cause might be a file removed by my antivirus software if that helps.

i have tried reinstaling the jdk and i have also looked at my path enviromental variable which seems to be in order, but i still have this problem.

Comment: Can you open the SDK Manager if you navigate to the installation folder of it?

Comment: i don't know the destination of the of that folder but i'll try looking for it

Comment: i could't find the folder

Comment: This is usually the SDK installation folder: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk` , but maybe I should rephrase my question: can you open the SDK manager at all? Because it could be simply that the folder of the SDK manager in Android Studio's settings is pointing to the wrong directory.

Comment: for me that destination looks like this C:\Users\Shark Gaming\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk  but from here i don't know what file is the SDK manager

Comment: If you mean SDK location under project structure that path and the path writen above are ecaxtly the same